# error: cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++ and wrote this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sumtype (double sum) {
if (sum>0)
    cout<<"P"<<endl;
else if (sum==0)
    cout<<"0"<<endl;
else
    cout<<"N"<<endl;
}

double sum (double a, double b) {
return a+b;
}

int main() {
char sumtype;
double a;
double b;
cout<<"input value of a: ";
cin>>a;
cout<<"input value of b: ";
cin>>b;
cout<<"sum= "<<sum (a,b)<<endl;
sumtype (sum);

}
```

However it always says error: 'sumtype' cannot be used as a function
  sumtype (sum);
              ^

What's the problem?

Comment: You've hidden the name of function `sumtype` by doing this: `char sumtype;`, making `sumtype` refer to a `char`.

Comment: Besides that, you're passing a function (`sum`) to `sumtype`.

Answer (score 4):

You have same name for function and variable change variable or function name and it will work. (e.g. char sumtype1;)

Comment: Or better yet, just remove it, as it doesn't seem to be used anywhere

Comment: And how that would make it work? The function `sumtype` expects a double, not a function pointer.